# What is the name of this type?

Tags: swift, types, terminology

In my app, I used a very complicated data structure:

```
[(category: String, items: [(String, String)])]
```

I know that:

- `[Int]` is "an array of `Int`"
- `(String, String)` is "a tuple of `String` and `String`"

So what should I call the above type?

Maybe

> An array of tuples of `String` and an array of tuples of `String` and `String`

?

But that sounds like three types:

```
[(String)] and [(String)] and String
```

which is a little confusing.

How should I call this type?

Comment: Why do you need to translate the type into English circumlocution? It's a Swift type, `[(category: String, items: [(String, String)])]`. That's not problematic (it's not what I would use in this situation, but it's not going to do you any harm). What's the trouble?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Does it matter what you call it  ? :\

Comment: @matt What should I say if I want to tell someone else that my variable is of this type?

Comment: You'd say `[(category: String, items: [(String, String)])]`

Comment: It called a "I should have used a struct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't over-use tuples. Create a type for the outer tuple:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var category : String
    var items : [(String, String)]
}
```

Now it's much easier to say what this is: it's an array of MyStruct.

Comment: Hmm... Why have I not thought of this? Thank you! So I guess a rule of thumb is "When it's confusing to say the type, create a struct"?